# Showing List Where ID is not Present

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table,

first is 
**master_location:**

this table is consist of column (id, location)

- row 1, id = 1 , location = X
- row 2, id = 2 , location = Y
- row 3, id = 3 , location = Z

second is 
**user_access**

column (email, id)

row 1 => me@localhost.host , 1

i want to show all other location from master location where email "me@localhost" is NOT present.

I've set up sql:

```
 SELECT ml.idms_location, ml.location
 FROM ms_location ml JOIN user_access tu
 WHERE ml.id= tu.id
 AND !(tu.email = 'me@localhost.host');
```

but it only show from table user_access where the email is NOT me@localhost.host

is there any sql syntax like SELECT ALL EXCEPT?

thanks

**UPDATE**

Table 1: master_location

[image: master location]

Tabel 2: tm_access

[image: tm acess]

i've write the syntax result as suggested:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ml.idms_location,ml.location
FROM ms_location ml
LEFT OUTER JOIN tm_userlocation tu
ON ml.idms_location = tu.idms_location
WHERE COALESCE(tu.email,'john@mscid.com') = 'john@mscid.com';
```

the result

[image: result sql]

**USING THIS SQL SYNTAX:**

```
SELECT ms.idms_location, ms.location
FROM ms_location AS ms LEFT JOIN tm_userlocation AS tu
ON ms.idms_location = tu.idms_location
WHERE tu.email !='john@mscid.com' OR tu.email IS NULL;
```

the result where i execute is only the first ID is missing, the no. 3 and no. 5 should removed too

screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following statement will return all rows from `ms_location` that have no corresponding row in `user_access`.

```
SELECT ml.idms_location,ml.location
FROM   master_location ml
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT *
          FROM   user_access tu
          WHERE  tu.idms_location = ml.idms_location
                 AND tu.email = 'john@mscid.com'
       )
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6afe6/5)

Comment: the syntax is resulting all data is showing. Please see the update.

Comment: i've try to your syntax but the result is the same as the new update "USING THIS SQL SYNTAX" only the first row is gone, the other two is still in the row (row 3 and 5). The row 3 and 5 should be gone too.

Comment: @randytan - It seems we all misinterpreted what you were asking. I have added a fiddle that should return the results as I now think you expect them <g>. Note that for future reference I would advise adding expected in and outputs to your question immediately as to prevent misunderstandings.

Answer (score 1):

You've left a bit to be guessed at (I'm assuming your cardinality is 1..*), but I think what you're asking for is a result set showing the ms_location records that don't have an associated user_access record with the email address 'me@localhost.host'. That is, from your given sample data, only location X has an associated user_access record with that email address (it's also the only record). Locations Y and Z do not have associated user_access records with the specified address. These are the ones you want.

If I've interpreted you correctly, try this:

```
SELECT ml.idms_location, ml.location
FROM ms_location ml
WHERE ml.id NOT IN (
  SELECT id FROM user_access WHERE email = 'me@localhost.host')
```

If I haven't, don't.

Answer (score 0):

As per your data Your Query should be

```
select m.`id`, m.`location` from `master_location` as m 
WHERE 
m.`id` NOT IN ( select `id` from `user_access` WHERE `email` = 'john@mscid.com' ) ;
```

Check the SQL Fiddle Link

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/28b50/3

Comment: i've add new update. The sql from you is working if only one values is present in user_access, if there are 2 or three value, the result is not working in my computer.

Comment: @randytan check out the SQL Demo for the updated sql as per your data